# The CSS button width not fitting the container width

Tags: reactjs, sass

[image: The upload button not fitting the content width]

**CreateProduct.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout/Layout'
import AdminMenu from '../../components/Layout/AdminMenu/AdminMenu'

import "./createProduct.scss"
import { Select } from 'antd'
import axios from 'axios'

const { Option } = Select

const CreateProduct = () => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [photo, setPhoto] = useState("")
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
    const [price, setPrice] = useState("")
    const [category, setCategory] = useState("")
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("")
    const [shipping, setShipping] = useState("")

    const getAllCategories = async() => {
        try{
            const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/category")
            if(data?.success){
                setCategories(data?.categories)
            }
        } catch(error){ 
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllCategories()
    }, [])

    const handleCreate = () => {

    }

    return (
        <Layout title={"Create Product - Dominic Ecommerce"}>
            <div className="create-container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="row-left">
                        <AdminMenu />
                    </div>
                    <div className="row-product">
                        <div className="card-product">
                            <h1>Create Product</h1>
                            <div className="category">
                                <Select className='select' bordered={false}
                                placeholder={"Select a category"} size='large'
                                showSearch onChange={(value) => setCategory(value)}>
                                    {categories?.map((c) => (
                                        <Option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                                            {c.name}
                                        </Option>
                                    ))}
                                </Select>
                                <div className="photo">
                                    <label>
                                        {photo ? photo.name : "Upload Photo"}
                                        <input type='file' name='photo' accept='image/*'
                                        onChange={(e) => setPhoto(e.target.files[0])} hidden />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {photo && (
                                        <div>
                                            <img src={URL.createObjectURL(photo)} alt='' 
                                            height={'200px'} />
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                                <div className="product-input">
                                    <label>Name:</label>
                                    <input type='text' value={name} placeholder='Enter Product Name'
                                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="product-input">
                                    <label>Description:</label>
                                    <textarea value={description} placeholder='Enter Product Description'
                                    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} rows="4" cols="50" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="product-input">
                                    <label>Price:</label>
                                    <input type='number' value={price} placeholder='Enter Product Price'
                                    onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="product-input">
                                    <label>Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type='number' value={quantity} placeholder='Enter Product Quantity'
                                    onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="product-input">
                                    <label>Shipping:</label>
                                    <Select className='shipping-select' bordered={false}
                                    placeholder={"Select shipping"} size='large'
                                    showSearch  onChange={(value) => setShipping(value)}>
                                        <Option value="0">No</Option>
                                        <Option value="1">Yes</Option>
                                    </Select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="product-input">
                                    <button onClick={handleCreate}>Create Product</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default CreateProduct
```

**createProduct.scss**

```
@use "../../App.scss" as app;

.create-container{
    height: 100vh;
    background: app.$gargo-gas;
    .row{
        display: flex;
        padding: 2rem;
        gap: 3rem;

        .row-product{
            // width: 70%;
            font-family: app.$font-ubuntu;

            .card-product{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;

                .category{
                    
                    .select{
                        width: 100%;
                        border: 1px solid rgb(124,124,124);
                        margin-top: 1rem;
                        border-radius: .5rem;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                    .photo{
                        margin: 2rem 0;
                        
                        label{
                            background-color: app.$polic-blue;
                            color: white;
                            text-align: center;
                            padding: 1rem;
                            width: 100%;
                            border-radius: .5rem;
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }
                    }
                    .product-input{
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                        gap: 2rem;
                        margin-bottom: 1rem;
                        label{
                            width: 30%;
                            text-align: start;
                        }
                        input{
                            width: 70%;
                            height: 38px;
                            padding: 0 10px;
                            // margin-bottom: 1rem;
                            border-radius: .5rem;
                            border: 1px solid rgb(124, 124, 124);
                            
                        }
                        textarea{
                            width: 70%;
                            border-radius: .5rem;
                            border: 1px solid rgb(124, 124, 124);
                            padding: 10px;
                        }
                        .shipping-select{
                            width: 100%;
                            margin-top: 1rem;
                            border-radius: .5rem;
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }
                        button{
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 38px;
                            padding: 0 11px;
                            margin: 1rem 0;
                            border-radius: .5rem;
                            border: 1px solid rgb(124, 124, 124);
                            cursor: pointer;
                            background-color: app.$polic-blue;
                            color: white;

                            &:hover{
                                background-color: app.$gargo-gas;
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                color: black;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to set the upload photo button width as large as other fields and even I set the width to 100% it still remains unchanged. What I want is the button having the same width as other row fields and the text could be aligned center. Can anyone help find out the solution?

Comment: `label` is an inline element by default, so `width` gets ignored. Make it `display: block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: It works fine now